# E_R MYSQL Crear tablas

Tags: mysql

Estoy peléandome con una tarea de MYSQL, soy muy nuevo y no sé muy bien como desarrollar el siguiente enunciado:

> Para cada tienda necesitamos almacenar la siguiente información: ID de tienda (único), direcciones de entrega (varias por tienda), límite de crédito de cada tienda (en ningún caso debe superar los 30.000 €), nivel de descuento que estará en función de la categoría de tienda y en ningún caso superará el 20%.
> Las tiendas se dividen en categorías, de acuerdo con el volumen de compras anuales, de forma que a mayor volumen de compra los descuentos serán mayores.
> Las tiendas realizan pedidos al mayorista, es fundamental identificar en el pedido la tienda que lo realiza, la dirección de entrega, así como la fecha en la que se realiza dicho pedido.
> Cada pedido dispone de líneas de pedido, en cada línea de pedido se determinará el identificador del artículo, descripción, su número de unidades y el importe de este.
> Los artículos se distribuyen a cada tienda por varios proveedores, para identificar a cada proveedor se tendrá en cuenta el ID de proveedor (único) y dirección de contacto.

He desarrollado el siguiente código para crear las tablas, pero a la hora de visualizar el diagrama E-R no me convence y estoy convencido de que lo he hecho mal.

```
CREATE DATABASE Tarea; USE Tarea;

CREATE TABLE ARTICULO ( 
 Codigo_articulo varchar(20) NOT NULL, fecha_compra date, ID_Tienda 
 varchar(25) NOT NULL, primary key (Codigo_articulo));

CREATE TABLE PEDIDOS ( 
 Codigo_articulo varchar (20) NOT NULL, descripcion varchar (20) NOT NULL, 
 unidades_articulo int, importe float, 
 primary key (Codigo_articulo), foreign key (Codigo_articulo) 
 references ARTICULO(Codigo_articulo)) ;

CREATE TABLE PROVEEDORES ( ID_proveedor varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
Direccion_contacto varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Codigo_articulo varchar (20) NOT NULL, primary key (ID_proveedor), 
foreign key (Codigo_articulo) 
references PEDIDOS(Codigo_articulo)) ;

CREATE TABLE TIENDA_MARCA ( 
 ID_Tienda varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
 Direccion_entrega1 varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
 Direccion_entrega2 varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
 Direccion_entrega3 varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
 primary key (ID_Tienda), foreign key (ID_Tienda) references 
 PROVEEDORES(Codigo_articulo), foreign key (ID_Tienda) references 
PEDIDOS(Codigo_articulo)) ;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es realmente el problema? "No me convence" no suena a un problema como tal... Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu intuición no te falla: la solución que planteas tiene múltiples errores de concepto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi sugerencia es que insertes un montón de saltos de línea en el enunciado y te vayas construyendo el modelo ER línea a línea:

```
Para cada tienda necesitamos almacenar la siguiente información: 
ID de tienda (único), 
direcciones de entrega (varias por tienda), 
límite de crédito de cada tienda (en ningún caso debe superar los 30.000 €), 
nivel de descuento que estará en función de la 
categoría de tienda y en ningún caso superará el 20%.

Las tiendas se dividen en categorías, 
de acuerdo con el volumen de compras anuales, 
de forma que a mayor volumen de compra los descuentos serán mayores. 

Las tiendas realizan pedidos al mayorista, 
es fundamental identificar en el pedido la tienda que lo realiza, 
la dirección de entrega, 
así como la fecha en la que se realiza dicho pedido.

Cada pedido dispone de líneas de pedido, 
en cada línea de pedido se determinará el identificador del artículo, 
descripción, 
su número de unidades y 
el importe de este.

Los artículos se distribuyen a cada tienda por varios proveedores, 
para identificar a cada proveedor se tendrá en cuenta el ID de proveedor (único) y 
dirección de contacto.
```

Te recomiendo utilizar la [Herramienta para edición de diagramas Dia](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.es), porque tendrás que realizar un montón de cambios conforme avances en el enunciado y, directamente en MySQL, tardarás mucho más en llegar a una solución que te cuadre.

Y, sobre todo, no tengas miedo a ir despacio. Ya se simplificará cuando analices las cardinalidades:

[image: Modelo ER]

Diferencia bien entre **entidades**, **relaciones** y **atributos**. Ante la duda, implementa la solución que propones en hojas de cálculo para ver si los datos están donde tienen que estar y practica mucho hasta que dejes de cometer errores de diseño.

Es normal que surjan preguntas mientras diseñas, anótalas para que te las aclaren. Por ejemplo: *¿Mayoristas y proveedores son lo mismo? ¿O en el enunciado sobreentienden que el mayorista únicamente vende y el proveedor te lo lleva a la tienda?*

Después, verás generalizaciones del tipo: `tiendas`, `mayoristas` y `proveedores` son todo `empresas` que contienen muchos datos en común, ¿por qué separar toda esa información en diferentes tablas? Pero, poco a poco...

Espero haberte aclarado más dudas que las que te he generado...